# Default installation still visible even after deleting the installation folder

Tags: php, docker, prestashop

please, when I want to run exist prestashop project (1.6.1.7) on docker, still showing me page of installation, but I have own DB. Where is a problem? Please, can you help me?
On stackoverflow I didn't found same question, which would help me.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  prestashop:
    image: prestashop/prestashop
    ports:
      - 82:80
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./../:/srv
      - ./../modules:/srv/modules
      - ./../themes:/srv/themes
      - ./../override:/srv/override
    environment:
      - PS_DEV_MODE=1
      - DB_SERVER=mysql
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWD={PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME={DB}
      - PS_INSTALL_AUTO=0

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: {PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: {DB}
      MYSQL_USER: db_write
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - ./data/db/:/var/lib/mysql:delegated

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: Adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

When I go to install my DB is removed which I don't want. I already tried to install the new database and then replace it with my database, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please remove the install folder from your project directory.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I deleted the installation folder and the admin folder.

Comment: Have you deleted admin folder? You are supposed to rename it, not delete.

Comment: why do you use `delegated` for the mysql volume? This might cause persistency issues when the container is restarted

Comment: Mihai: Delegated to use in case someone wants to run it on a MACbook